# yadcf select2 display issues

Tags: jquery-select2, yadcf

Using yadcf, I'm trying to provide a select box that will allow multiple selections.  I've checked several resources that showed examples, and I've tried incorporating them in to the program, but I have had no luck.  Here is the code I've used that got me the closest:

```
{column_number: 4, filter_type: 'multi_select', select_type: 'select2', filter_container_id: 'filter_devtype', select_type_options: {dropdownAutoWidth: true, placeholder: 'All'} },
```

The above code does give the filter that shows an arrow for the drop down, but the width is 0, so I can't see any of the items in the drop down.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: inspect the showcase page of yadcf + select2 http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_select2.html and provide a test page with your issue (use any js playground)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you need me to do to create a test page that will be helpful here.

Comment: re create your issue in a jsbin / jsfiddle so I can see what you did and try to help you

Comment: This is part of a very large source file.  When I add just the first 3 javascript source files to jsbin, I get a message that the source is too large to save.  I'm not sure what the best path forward is.

However, my boss and I were playing around with the CSS styles using Chrome's tools.  We were able to get the text box to show the proper size (the rest of it didn't work).  So we assume we have a CSS conflict somewhere.

Comment: make sure you included yadcf css and select2 css files, about the jsbin sample page - create a minimal demo that reproduces your issue (no need for all your project)